# Unable to submit image button as not able to locate web element?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

For the below website, html link:

http://www.travelcube.com/uk/Home.jsp;jsessionid=1520F064FE65C29BB1D9F891B8F88890.01IJW?page=CurrencyUL.jsp&siteid=viewtrip&lang=E

...can you have answer for this query?

I am unable to click the Go button, even though using classname,xpath method.
can any one help us how to click that button?

Comment: Can you consider working on the Answers provided on your previous Questions by our SO volunteers, work on those and Accept/Close those discussions before raising a new Question? Thanks

Comment: Seems we need to login to access the intended page, can you provide the dummy credentials? Thanks

Comment: No login id and pwd ... i just used below link to access this url:

Comment: driver.manage().window().maximize();
  driver.get("http://www.travelcube.com/uk/enter.jsp?siteid=viewtrip&lang=E&Start=CurrencyUL.jsp");

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer to your Question:

The `Go` button is within a frame. So first you need to switch to the frame then locate the element and perform `click()` as follows:

```
//your code lines
driver.switchTo().frame("Main");
//your code lines
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@name='go']")).click();
```

> Alternative `xpath` :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//form[@name='main']//button[@name='go']")).click();   

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//form[@name='main']//button[text()='GO']")).click();
```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//button[@name='go']"}

Comment: @Suresh Check my updated Answer and let me know the status. Thanks

Comment: No the above provided doesnt work ... i tried all the ways.. still showing unable to locate element..

Answer (score 0):

Try with CSS instead.

```
driver.switchTo().frame("main");
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("tr .buttonImage")).click();
```